# How to join hydrological data from a big area with a small area with better pixel resolution?

Tags: interpolation, hydrology, taudem

I use TAUDEM to make hydrologic analysis.
I have a hidro 1K dem file from South America (big area) pixel resolution=1000x1000 meters.
I have a specific dem file located in Brazil (small area) pixel resolution=30x30 meters.
There is no problem to calculate contributing area, slope, streams, etc for each dem file.
My problem is that I need to calculate the small area including data from the big area, for example the contributing area and the stream upslope length.
What is the best way to do this?